# How to make Adwaita Dark theme apply only to certain applications?

Tags: gnome, themes

Is this possible to apply Adwaita Dark theme only to some applications?

I want to enable it for the Terminal and maybe Nautilus but not other applications, because Opera and Software Center and possibly other non GTK applications look ugly/unreadable with Adwaita Dark theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For GTK2 apps, the way to do this was relatively simple. You can launch a gtk2 app with a custom theme like this:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=(path-to-theme) (command)
```

So for example, this worked:

```
GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Redmond/gtk-2.0/gtkrc catfish
```

(Catfish is an app I know to be gtk2 -- you may not have it installed.)

Unfortunately, this feature broke entirely in GTK3. I can't gaurantee this will work perfectly, but you could try making simple shell scripts that configure a theme, launch the app, then unconfigure the theme. If you launch two apps at the same time, that my result in a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) with unpredictable results.

So for example, you could launch gedit like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -h ~/.config/gtk-3.0 ]
  then
    rm ~/.config/gtk-3.0
fi
ln -s /usr/share/themes/HighContrast/gtk-3.0 ~/.config
gedit "$@" &
sleep 1
if [ -h ~/.config/gtk-3.0 ]
  then
    rm ~/.config/gtk-3.0
fi
```

Besides the race condition, doing this has some other undesirable side-effects. For one, you'll use more memory for each application that has its own theme. For another, you'll have to write custom shell scripts and launchers for each app. Finally, in my opinion, your desktop will look weird.

But there. That's how you can do it, sort of.

Answer (score 0):

No, theme is for entire applications
but some applications like monodevelop allows to chose specific theme for it(it applies for some java apps too)